# How is this PMOS FET working as ESD protection?

Tags: esd, surge-protection

Can somebody please explain the circuit functionality? I'm thinking of PMOS (\$V_{sg}=0\$) as a current-limiting diode. Am I right?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Such an N-channel MOSFET works just like a TVS or ESD diode, that is:

- if V<sub>DD</sub> has a 'normal' voltage relative to DGND, then neither the MOSFET nor the body diode conduct;
- if V<sub>DD</sub> has a (large) negative voltage, then the body diode is forward biased and conducts;
- if V<sub>DD</sub> has a large positive voltage, then the body diode and/or the MOSFET break down and conduct.

The MOSFETs are not used for switching in any case.

Answer (score 0):

In the bottom right circuit, there are 2 NMOS devices used for ESD protection. The "diodes" in parallel will be for (-) ESD events.

From what I've been taught by the in-house ESD guy, the circuits are very layout-dependent; the location of metal-active contacts, the placing of metal over active where displacement currents from high dV/dT Efield transients, the adjacency of gate-poly to metal, the placement of substrate contacts needed to move enormous transient currents **DEEP** into the bulk material and dissipate ESD heat in the **volume** of material instead of at the (shallow) surface FET implants ---- all must be planned.

And tested. And probably will fail under transient tests because the desired SNAPBACK
behavior occurs at the WRONG voltage and downstream gate-oxides will be over stressed. So a phase2 design/fab/test is needed.

It ain't magic, but thus throwing down any old FET dopants, with casual metallization and contacts and bulk ties ------ does not suffice.

The FETs and the various layout methods are crafted to impose a BIPOLAR SNAPBACK at a low voltage, with huge currents steered to flow only DEEP below the FETs.

Comment: How does the NMOS with gate-source shorted together protect against ESD?

Comment: I think the NMOS is in depletion mode, which means Vgs=0, and the device is normally on and conducts current. In this mode, the Id flows from drain to source at a particular Vds. I believe what it does is conducting the huge current peak due to ESD spike at a fix rate. I'm not sure what the diode is doing here though besides protection. I mean how does the combination of these two work together.